# django unsuccessful login fail page

Tags: django, django-registration

I am using [django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/) and would like to have a different page for failed logins. The initial login screen is loaded via jQuery, so doesn't need to extend the base page:

```
{% extends 'base.htm' %}
```

but the "fail" page does need to extend it. I cannot "if" an extends tag because it needs to be the first tag on the page.

So! I thought to load a different login-fail page, but I haven't the foggiest how to do that - how do I specify a different login-fail page?

Comment: How do you know that the login has failed? If that logic is in your view, just redirect the users to another page.

Comment: @TrevorSenior wha? I know the login has failed because i get redirected to the "you failed" page - which is the same page as the initial login screen. I'm not touching the logic at all, i am using django-registration, so i just let it do whatever it wants to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sigh.

So the login page needs to be changed - i suppose i could extend and override it in a child class - maybe i will so i don't lose all my logic!

Yeah, i cut and paste it into my own views.py file

Ok, so all i done was add an "else" after the form.is_valid check that sets a variable (failed) to true.

And then, at the end of the method, when i render_to_response, i run a check to see if failed is True - and if so, just render to a different login page (failedLogin.html) ~ where this one does extend base.htm.

yay!